# asp.net check if a file from the Response.OutputStream has been saved/opened

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, epplus

I am building an excel file (using EPPLUS) on a web page which gives the option to either save or open the file.

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=Excel_List.xlsx");
package.SaveAs(Response.OutputStream);
Response.End();
```

That works fine. I just want to know how can I check if the user has either opened/saved the file?
Is there an event for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest answer is you cannot. Once the server has handed the file off to the client ASP.NET has no control over it.

You could, in theory, place a macro in the Excel file to call a URL on your server, but that's assuming the user opens the Excel file and allows for the execution of the macro (which is disabled in modern Excel versions).

Comment: I thought this might be the case, just wondering if there is a work around but guess there isn't. Will need to look into an alternate solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot determine it. After the output is generated you have no info about download process or actions that user takes on downloaded file. It is caused mostly by web browser security limitations.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not what HTTP is for. If you can successfully send all data from the server, you may assume the client has received it all. Client may then discard, save, print, copy, do whatever they like with the data.

If you want to perform such a check, you should do it from the Excel file itself. But then again you shouldn't, because of privacy. If I ever caught an Excel file phoning home, I don't know what'll happen.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to know if they actually opened it in Excel without adding a macro to the file, but there are ways that you can send a confirmation to the server that the download was completed successfully.  For this you would need to embed a rich client in the browser to handle the HTTP request rather than doing it with the browser alone.  Something like  [SoftArtisans XFile](http://fileup.softartisans.com/professional-file-transfer-solution) can be used for this.  Our .NET Excel library also comes with an ActiveX control that can manage the download process (called the [OfficeWriter Assistant](http://support.softartisans.com/docs/OfficeWriter/OfficeWriterAssistant/WebHelp/whatis.htm)).

Disclaimer: I work for SoftArtisans